# FTP server user adding

Tags: 12.04, server, ftp, vsftpd

Im setting up a ftp server using vsftp and i need to ask it:How in the world you set your login details?
Ive found on the internet a lot of guides, but all say to add users in a specific file, BUT where do you set your password and most are about setting up the server so it can run(including the ubuntu ftp server guide).Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer so im adding it here for others with my problem to know: users are the pc/server's users created on your pc/server